Migrate Server Essentials 2016 to Server Essentials 2022
I have a client needing to retire a server essentials 2016 with a new server essentials 2022. .  File sharing on the servers only.  Knowing there are limitations to SE, I'm trying to make a plan that will make it as painless as possible.  Thoughts:
Add new server as a dc in the domain.  Allow replication.
Move files to new server, create shares.
Move FSMO roles.  I believe this will start a 21 day countdown on how long the SE server will run without FSMO roles assigned.
Demote old server and remove.
I think all of that will work fine (but if you see problems, please let me know!).  From there I'm trying to figure out the best way to have the clients use the new server for their mapped drives and shortcuts-they are mapped manually now-without having to touch every workstation.
I'm thinking setting up a batch file to remap drives.  Would a cname work to point them to the right server?  Any gotchas?

If you go the different server name route, using a CNAME is one of the few practical options. You can also create a CNAME for the short single label name using the GlobalNames zone. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/set-dnsserverglobalnamezone

Thanks.  Is there a path to renaming the server and using the same ip address that doesn't upset anything?  Would this make more sense?
